# Decode Html code to unicode java

Tags: java, html, unicode

I am trying to find a quick way to decode html numbers (not just special characters) and convert them to unicode in Java. For example, I would like to be able to convert "&#1042 ;&#1085 ;&#1091 ;&#1090 ;&#1088 ;&#1077 ;&#1085 ;&#1085 ;&#1080 ;&#1081 ;"
to "Внутренний." I just can't seem to find a way to do it.

Comment: this is not a duplicate I had already tried that answer and if you do System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml("&#1042;&#1085;&#1091;&#1090;&#1088;&#1077;&#1085;&#1085;&#1080;&#1081;")); you get ??????? which is not correct

Comment: ??????? is correct, the problem is that you cannot see the characters it represents, because the font does not have glyphs for those characters. (so then the font uses ?'s instead)